# How to consider timezones in a bridge

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timezone

I need to transfer records between two systems based on their time.

One end is an sql server database, and the datefields (currently) have `datetime` columns with values filled from `getdate()` - no timezone info anywhere. The field is called `upddate`.

The other end is an api to another database. It returns JSON files in which the date properties are like this:
`"registeredAt": "2018-11-29T08:41:17.214+0000"`

This last one seems fortunately to include timezone info. The question, then, is: What should I apply to the sql server's `upddate` field in order to compare it to a `registeredAt` value?

By searching around I found the `datetimeoffset` type that might be of use - however, I am very buffled by the fact that `select convert(datetimeoffset,getdate(),127)` returns a result with +00:00 in the end, despite the server being on a non-zero offset timezone.

Comment: `GETDATE()` changes it's value based on the timezone the server is in (and day light savings). If timezone information is important, then I would start using something like `GETUTCDATE()`, or `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`  instead.

Comment: What are you doing in the middle?  I assume you are writing an application to do the transfering from SQL Server to the API?  If so, you are better off doing the time zone conversion there.  Tell us more about that part of your solution.